# B2C OAuth2 API error: Signature validation failed. Unable to resolve SecurityKeyIdentifier: 'SecurityKeyIdentifier

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have spent quite a bit of time getting our .NET MVC web application to integrate with Azure Active Directory B2C, with reasonable success, using a custom profile to allow users of other Azure Active Directories to log in to us.

Now I want to incorporate an API, roughly following this process:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi

I say roughly because I'm trying to fit this functionality into an application that's already been under development for several months.

I'm using Postman to hit this URL a and get a bearer token:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/ourtenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token

I use the grant_type=client_credentials, and the client_id and client_secret specified in Active Directory (added in the the "not-B2C" App registrations blade because apparently B2C doesn't yet support the client_credentials flow)

It appears to work fine and I get a response like this:

```
{
"token_type": "Bearer",
"expires_in": "3599",
"ext_expires_in": "0",
"expires_on": "1513906161",
"not_before": "1513902261",
"resource": "00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
"access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Ing0Nzh4eU9wbHNNMUg3TlhrN1N4MTd4MXVwYyIsImtpZCI6Ing0Nzh4eU9wbHNNMUg3TlhrN1N4MTd4MXVwYyJ9.eyJhdWQiOiIwMDAwMDAwMi0wMDAwLTAwMDAtYzAwMC0wMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAiLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3N0cy53aW5kb3dzLm5ldC83YjY1ZDY0NC0xNDM0LTQxZDQtYTFhMC04MjVlZjgwOTAyZDMvIiwiaWF0IjoxNTEzOTAyMjYxLCJuYmYiOjE1MTM5MDIyNjEsImV4cCI6MTUxMzkwNjE2MSwiYWlvIjoiWTJOZ1lKaTJWbkhKTXQwNUcrZmMrL2pFNmRQLzdRQT0iLCJhcHBpZCI6IjZkZmVkNGVkLTU2ZDktNDQ5Ny04M2JhLTkzOWJmNGI3OGUyNSIsImFwcGlkYWNyIjoiMSIsImlkcCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vc3RzLndpbmRvd3MubmV0LzdiNjVkNjQ0LTE0MzQtNDFkNC1hMWEwLTgyNWVmODA5MDJkMy8iLCJvaWQiOiIxYTYxNGM5Yy00Nzc5LTQ2OTctOThjNC05OWNlZTJlZTVkY2IiLCJzdWIiOiIxYTYxNGM5Yy00Nzc5LTQ2OTctOThjNC05OWNlZTJlZTVkY2IiLCJ0ZW5hbnRfcmVnaW9uX3Njb3BlIjoiTkEiLCJ0aWQiOiI3YjY1ZDY0NC0xNDM0LTQxZDQtYTFhMC04MjVlZjgwOTAyZDMiLCJ1dGkiOiJjV2lzVmxDRDEwdW9Ra3BHbWRBdkFBIiwidmVyIjoiMS4wIn0.BiXHI5Sp0t2k_npJYdWjclSXGOMbxniR8G1ifOCNUuiNUZRFG6DsbIqkJEBXSFFUxQpvtGkBaI5oF2u4oJ5Ed37thh_gOLJ1TKBaubGusv7vgUVoIk9A5F8H_HeX57zyRR2XU3czdSC4uZC_XpVwV7eT4-Z4bNooL0WJi1ZNx6ZFBC4qktNf7yifc7-iAEEDTWj3clwA81RJwAe9YbUMI3q640sNg8QlrZDiKFzuEuFocHces0bAYSyfLu5cwDw2wvJwQzYEMahjQ3V7RXpqg-YktsUoSTkLOHm7QNrM2Pko8ZAye58O-nTv1gD5yYDZ8st74x4MUHhNZhaR44byjw"
```

}

When I use this bearer token in the Authorization header an API call, I get the response:

```
{"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}
```

I switched on diagnostic tracing and found this in the output:

```
Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthBearerAuthenticationMiddleware Error: 0 : Authentication failed
System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException: IDX10500: Signature validation failed. Unable to resolve SecurityKeyIdentifier: 'SecurityKeyIdentifier
    (
    IsReadOnly = False,
    Count = 2,
    Clause[0] = X509ThumbprintKeyIdentifierClause(Hash = 0xC78EFCC723A996C3351FB35793B4B1D7BC75BA97),
    Clause[1] = System.IdentityModel.Tokens.NamedKeySecurityKeyIdentifierClause
    )
', 
token: '{"typ":"JWT","alg":"RS256","x5t":"x478xyOplsM1H7NXk7Sx17x1upc","kid":"x478xyOplsM1H7NXk7Sx17x1upc"}.{"aud":"00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000","iss":"https://sts.windows.net/7b65d644-1434-41d4-a1a0-825ef80902d3/","iat":1513901664,"nbf":1513901664,"exp":1513905564,"aio":"Y2NgYPg7bbbRmu/aXjwejXZs73e5AgA=","appid":"6dfed4ed-56d9-4497-83ba-939bf4b78e25","appidacr":"1","idp":"https://sts.windows.net/7b65d644-1434-41d4-a1a0-825ef80902d3/","oid":"1a614c9c-4779-4697-98c4-99cee2ee5dcb","sub":"1a614c9c-4779-4697-98c4-99cee2ee5dcb","tenant_region_scope":"NA","tid":"7b65d644-1434-41d4-a1a0-825ef80902d3","uti":"5nMOpv6eok60JyzWwksuAA","ver":"1.0"}
RawData: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Ing0Nzh4eU9wbHNNMUg3TlhrN1N4MTd4MXVwYyIsImtpZCI6Ing0Nzh4eU9wbHNNMUg3TlhrN1N4MTd4MXVwYyJ9.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.mPzogfR2ndo89P-qWIypdPjrrBb0uEOO0Fo-H164C4Rm21zFQpkwVSFe-NP4MtvMnB5fJdhzGxzPDACFHBiQi7k7ZZVGv5bWaIbhGlPmKCQ1j6XaweYp7pm66R-RIsokZvR87nJ4ZkvYJIkuxnXPjChC-3FjsLDf43FKcByDPvvJKpVj48JW9N79vq77HQ2w8bnq172zOUflxGbuC2nDiwzkgWQiFboL-H3LLUxHqZHeE46u7pDSOrE3DSY1F5aPqBq1IDCg6ELcBcaLN27509oAH2rghkvXjHWOs9Nw3tszVoza7CpEGV7fjtSGN874GV_vx-ziqIOf1EgSBPEH6Q'.
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateSignature(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(String securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, SecurityToken& validatedToken)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt.JwtFormat.Unprotect(String protectedText)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthBearerAuthenticationHandler.<AuthenticateCoreAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The sample that you linked shows you how to secure and call a web API using Azure AD B2C. It seems like you are trying to obtain an Azure AD token, and then trying to use that to sign into an API that is secured using Azure AD B2C.

While client credentials is not supported in Azure AD B2C, it doesn't seem like you need the client credential flow. Client credential flow is used for an API to API call. If you want to call an API from the app that the users are signing into, you can use access tokens. Check out this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-access-tokens

Comment: Hmm. Yes we have secured both the app and the API with B2C. We now want to expose an API that can be called from external backend services to do some data uploads. The API is not intended to be called using cookies and/or by interactive users. We followed this approach to allow external AD users to authenticate via B2C: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-aad-custom and I was hoping the API would magically work via client_credentials. I now suspect we might need to secure the API with AD proper, as B2C users don't really need to call the API.

Comment: Yes!! I was able to secure the API via Azure AD and execute an API call using Postman, whilst leaving Azure B2C authentication intact in the same project for user logins. I used this sample as a guide for the API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-service-to-service. You steered me in the right direction, do you want to propose a further answer along these lines and I'll accept it?